# Seperate Shipping Rate for Certain Items Based On Order Value

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods

I need to set up a separate shipping rate for bulky items based on the total order value

For example total order value of bulky items is less than $1,000 shipping is $100 
Order value is between $1,000 - 1,500 shipping is $150

How can i do this and still leave the shipping rates for the other products the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use table rate shipping method.

- Go to Store >> Setting >> Configration >> Sales >> Shipping Methods >> Table Rates.
- In the upper-left corner, set Store View to “Main Website”, or to any other website where the configuration applies. When prompted to confirm, tap OK.
- The Export and Import options now appear in the Table Rates section, with “Use Default” checkboxes to the right of each option.
- Select Condition to "Price v. Destination".
- To change the Condition, clear the Use Default checkbox. Then, choose another option.
- Click Export CSV.
- Save the tablerates.csv file to your computer. It will look like this.

  [image]
- Edit tablerates.csv and import again.
- Visit [this site](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html#step-2-prepare-the-table-rate-data) to get clear idea.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: How can i do this so that only bulky items are subject to these rules, for example if a customer has an order value of $1000 of the 'Normal' items i want the shipping to be as before not to be charged at the bulky rate